# Need to fill nail holes in fiber cement siding

Tags: siding

What type of product should I use to fill nail holes in fiber cement siding? Nail holes are from a flag pole I removed.

Comment: Urethane caulk is available in custom colors to match your siding (assuming factory paint). I'd contact the manufacturer.

Comment: scrape a hidden portion of the board to get some dust to mix into the wet patch material for best matching.

Answer (score 2):

The installation guide for Hardie Board, which is a brand of cement board siding recommends using caulking to fill nail holes.  When I've installed it I used a high-quality exterior paintable calking after smoothing the edge of the holes.

Once the caulk is dry you can touch up the paint.

Answer (score 1):

I have been caulking screw holes and joints in Hardie Cedar Mill 4' x 8' sheets with Quad Max, no problems, seems to work great.